# Get string inside html tag - VB.Net

Tags: html, vb.net

So, i have this html code:

```
<div class="keyboard">
  <p>
    Hello world!
  </p>
</div>
```

I want to get text "Hello world!". I've tried with my regex code below, yet it didn't work.

```
Dim findtext2 As String = "(?<=<div class=""keyboard"">)(.*?)(?=</div>)"
Dim myregex2 As String = TextBox1.Text 'HTML code above
Dim doregex2 As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(myregex2, findtext2)
Dim matches2 As String = ""
For Each match2 As Match In doregex2
    matches2 = matches2 + match2.ToString + Environment.NewLine
Next
MsgBox(matches2)
```

Comment: Seems to me you're missing an end quote on line 2. Not actually a .NET expert, so I could be wrong :P

Comment: **'** character is used for comments, it doesn't need ending.

Comment: Well, that's confusing. In basically every other language, it's either a syntax error or a string/char literal.

Comment: Just ignore that comment, it's meant to people reading code and it doesn't affect it either.

Comment: Extracting html with regex's is a nuisance and a bit error prone. Maybe try [the html agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). Or if it's xhtml  then use one of the xml api's

Comment: Perhaps the most famous post on SO addresses [Parsing HTML with RegEx](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1070452)

Comment: You should definitely use HTML Agility Pack rather than Regex to parse HTML.

Comment: I would if i know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in comments don't use ReGex for parsing html code.
Instead use LINQ to XML

```
Dim html As XElement =
    <html>
        <body>
            <div class = "keyboard">
                <p>Hello word!</p>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>

Dim values As String = 
    html.Descendants("div").
         Where(Function(div) div.Attribute("class").Value.Equals("keyboard")).
         Select(Function(div) div.Element("p").Value)

For Each value As String in values
    Console.WriteLine(value);
End For
```

Comment: Gives error (on first line): **Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement**.

Comment: Are you wrapped html code with the quotes? If so remove quotes. [XML Literals Overview (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384629.aspx)

Comment: I've put it in TextBox and wrote **Dim html As XElement = TextBox1.Text**.

Comment: Then use `Dim html As XElement = XElement.Parse(TextBox1.Text);`